# Hydroponic Basil: massive root growth, but little leaf growth

Tags: basil, hydroponic

I am trying to grow some basil using the Kratky method under some cfl lighting. The root growth is massive and is almost filling my 1L jar. But the plant it self is not growing that much. 1 month in and I still have not been able to harvest even once.

What could the reason be for this? I am feeding using GH flora series, and it sits under a total of 150W cfl lighting (3700k / 6500k mixture).

Comment: Not higher than 25C (77F) I'd say. And the roots are white and look super healthy.

Comment: I did not add any rooting hormones or anything extra besides the GH nutrients. The PH is around 6,2

Comment: Also, the stem has grown quite a bit, and is now as thick as a pencil. I even had to cut up the net pot as it almost seemed to strangle the roots.